# Oracle Linked Server query error

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, linked-server

We have a problem with a query from a SQL Server 2008R2 - 64bit
to an Oracle Linked Server.

We use the Oracle 64-bit driver for Windows.

When we query a certain table we get the following error:

> Msg 7347, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider 'OraOLEDB.Oracle'
>   for linked server 'SERV_VISION2' returned data that does not match
>   expected data length for column
>   '[SERV_VISION2]..[VISION].[INV_M001].CUS_NM'. The (maximum) expected
>   data length is 30, while the returned data length is 24.

The problem seems to be the data in the CUS_NM column.
In the rows where he gives this error the data is like this:

```
¿¿¿
```

So like a question mark but upside down. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the
length of the column, for one reason he can't handle this data I guess.

Did anyone experience this problem?
Anyone a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

That's most likely an NLS (language) problem and you've got customer names with characters your database cannot handle. You'll need to determine the actual type of the CUS_NM column in the Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle object names are all uppercase by default. The linked-server query must exactly match the case of all referenced Oracle metadata, such as schema and table names.

Answer (score -3):

Try below way-

```
CAST(CUS_NM AS VARCHAR(50))
```

here casting can vary as per your data type.